# Dict with array key in julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

In julia language (ver 1.1.0), I am experimenting what would happen when I mutate a dictionary key.

Before mutation, both the variable `x` and `[1,2,3]` is recognized.

```
x = [1,2,3]; d = Dict(x=>"x")
haskey(d, x)
# true

haskey(d, [1,2,3])
# true
```

Once I mutate `x`, neither the variable `x` nor `[1,2,3,4]` is recognized.

```
push!(x, 4)
haskey(d, x)
# false

haskey(d, [1,2,3,4])
# false

haskey(d, [1,2,3])
# false
```

Value-wise, the key is "equal" to `x`, so I guess this has something to do with the hash function, but could not understand the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/80516ca20297a67b996caa08c38786332379b6a5/base/abstractarray.jl#L2103).

```
collect(keys(d))[1] == x == [1,2,3,4]
# true
```

Can someone explain what makes this behavior, or suggest resources that I should look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key function to look into is [`ht_keyindex`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl#L278).

There you can see that in order for the key to be found it must both:

- Match hash value (via [`hashindex`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl#L282)).
- Match [identity or value](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl#L289).

There is a non-negligible probability that after mutating `x` it will have the same `hashindex` value and the key would be found. For example here you could set index 4 of `x` to 5 and all seemingly would work:

```
julia> x[4] = 5
5

julia> x
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 5

julia> haskey(d, x)
true
```

Therefore - as in any programming language supporting dictionaries in a similar way - mutating keys of the dictionary should not be done. The above discussion should be in practice only a theoretical one.